# Convergence of Fourier series for a sum which is not uniform convergent

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, uniform-convergence

> Given $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos nt}{n}$$is it a fourier series in
>
> a. $L^2(\mathbb T)$?
>
> b. $C(\mathbb{T})$?

Usually when we get a series we use Weierstrass M test in order to find the sum is uniformly convergent, hence the function to which the series converges is continuous.  Here, this test won't work since $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\bigg|\frac{\cos nt}{n}\bigg|\le \sum_n\frac 1 n=\infty$$ We notice that the fourier coefficients (if it's a fourier series) are defined by $c_k=\frac{1}{2k}$.

How can we prove that in this case the series converges to a function ? Suppose we did so and not by uniform convergence: how would we disprove the continuity of the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

1. $\mathcal F: L^2(\mathbb T) \to \ell^2(\mathbb Z)$ is an isometry if defined via the complex fourier transform. Can you see that the complex fourier coefficients are in $\ell^2(\mathbb Z)$?
2. Evaluate the series at $t=0$. Can this be continuous?

Comment: 1. Yes.  thanks. 2. It that enough that in one point the function diverges to prove the function is not continuous?

Comment: @DanisFischer Yes, because continuous functions on compact sets are bounded.

Comment: Makes sense. thanks again. Last question: what if I was given a space which is not compact?

Comment: Picking a compact subset the same argument applies. This will unlikely occur to you in this context, though.

Comment: But if we can't? (For example take $\mathbb{R}$ with $\tau_{disc}$, which doesn't contain any compact subspace)?

Comment: @DanisFischer AFAIK, $\{x\}$ is compact in $\tau_{\text{disc}}$. The point is if the series diverges somewhere, the function isn't defined at that point of divergence.